# How can I build a desktop rig with awareness of Linux driver support?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics

I've been plagued by driver problems with each of the three laptops on which I've tried to install Ubuntu, usually because of Nvidia Optimus problems (somewhat solved by bumblebee but not quite).

Now I'm thinking of investing in building a desktop, but I'm a bit afraid of doing so because I'm not sure if what I build will be able to support 3 screens and good audio output.
How can I choose my graphics cards and audio cards with to ensure good driver support with Linux?

Is there an established way of checking compatibility other than looking things up on forums card by card?
Or is this unnecessary, and support woes are more a laptop than a desktop problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops have more exotic hardware by nature & unless Ubuntu Certified, can be a gamble. Tower setups fare better especially if you stick to Intel hardware. You can always try System 76, otherwise Google is your friend.